# SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have the below controller (testing purposes, it's not following REST with 2 GETs):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    private readonly IWeatherService _weatherService;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IWeatherService weatherService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _weatherService = weatherService;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherSummary")]
    [Route("getweatherforecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return _weatherService.GetWeatherSummary();
    }


    [HttpGet(Name = "Error")]
    [Route("error")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Error()
    {
        throw new Exception("some error message");
    }
}
```

I  have 2 GET methods in there, both not taking any params.  I tried adding a Route to each one and Name as well, but Swagger still shows the error:

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET api/WeatherForecast"

I'm able to hit both in postman using:

http://localhost:5000/api/WeatherForecast/getweatherforecast

http://localhost:5000/api/WeatherForecast/error

Does swagger not allow this, as they are both GET and both don't take any params, so it can't distinguish between them?  the Name or Route is not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherSummary")]
    
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        ......
    }


    [HttpGet(Name = "Error")]
    
    public Task<IActionResult> Error()
    {
        ......
    }
```

Or

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getweatherforecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            ......
        }
    
    
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("error")]
        public Task<IActionResult> Error()
        {
            ......
        }
```

Comment: The second approach worked for me, but i'm curious why doesn't what I have then work?  I had the Route attribute in both as well, the Name was there but why would that cause the error?